# Need help in optimizing sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to sql and have created the below sql to fetch the required results.However the query seems to take ages in running and is quite slow. It will be great if any help in optimization is provided.

Below is the sql query i am using:

```
SELECT
  Date_trunc('week',a.pair_date) as pair_week,
  a.used_code,
  a.used_name,
  b.line,
  b.channel,
  count(
    case when b.sku = c.sku then used_code else null end
  )
from
  a
  left join b on a.ma_number = b.ma_number
  and (a.imei = b.set_id or a.imei = b.repair_imei
  )
  left join c on a.used_code = c.code
group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Are the left joins really necessary?  If you are missing the rows where b.line and b.channel are NULL (which will have no count, either) will that be a problem?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do all help.

Comment: Please read https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions#Guide_to_Asking_Slow_Query_Questions, especially about showing EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS).

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the query as:

```
select Date_trunc('week',a.pair_date) as pair_week,
       a.used_code, a.used_name, b.line, b.channel,
       count(*) filter (where b.sku = c.sku)
from a left join
     b 
     on a.ma_number = b.ma_number and
        a.imei in ( b.set_id, b.repair_imei ) left join
     c
     on a.used_code = c.code
group by 1,2,3,4,5;
```

For this query, you want indexes on `b(ma_number, set_id, repair_imei)` and `c(code, sku)`.  However, this doesn't leave much scope for optimization.

There might be some other possibilities, depending on the tables.  For instance, `or`/`in` in the `on` clause is usually a bad sign -- but it is unclear what your intention really is.